# SharePoint 2016: Transaction (Process ID 58) was deadlocked on lock resources

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, sql, sql-server-2017

I receive the following error when attempting to create a new SharePoint 2016 Configuration db in SQL 2017.

PS command and Error:

> The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are
>   not registered. PS C:\Users\spintall> New-SPConfigurationDatabase
>   -DatabaseName SharePoint_Config -DatabaseServer dbname -AdministrationContentDatabaseName SharePoint_Admin_Content_DB -LocalServerRole SingleServerFarm
>
> cmdlet New-SPConfigurationDatabase at command pipeline position 1
>   Supply values for the following parameters: FarmCredentials
>   Passphrase: ******** New-SPConfigurationDatabase : Transaction
>   (Process ID 56) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process
>   and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. The
>   EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_send_dbmail', database
>   'msdb', schema 'dbo'. At line:1 char:1
>   + New-SPConfigurationDatabase -DatabaseName SharePoint_Config -Database ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...urationDatabase:SPCmdletNewSPConfigurationDatabase)
>   [New    -SPConfigurationDatabase], SqlException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewSPConfigurationDatabase

Environment:

SQL 2017 / SharePoint 2016

I'm logged into the SharePoint server as spinstall.  spinstall is a local admin on the server and has the following server roles in SQL: dbcreator, public and securityadmin.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like two thing missing from your command, PassPhrase and FarmCrednetials. You have add those in your command then run it again. Like this

```
New-SPConfigurationDatabase -DatabaseName SharePoint_Config -DatabaseServer dbname  -Passphrase (ConvertTo-SecureString "MyPassword" -AsPlainText -force) -FarmCredentials (Get-Credential) -AdministrationContentDatabaseName SharePoint_Admin_Content_DB -LocalServerRole SingleServerFarm
```

[New-SPConfigurationDatabase](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/new-spconfigurationdatabase?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: Thanks Waqas.  Same message after adding -passphrase and -farm credentials to the command.  After running the command I supplied above, I was prompted to enter farm credentials and passphrase.

Comment: are you providing the SPinstall credential in the farm or it is different account? could you please check the SQL server logs as well?

Comment: The farm credential is a different account (spfarm).  I'm checking sql server logs.

Comment: that account also required the DB creator and Security admin rights on SQL server

Comment: I added spfarm with dbcreator, public, securityadmin and same deadlock message.

Comment: whats on the SQL log? may be restart the SQL services, is that sql server is being shared with other application?

Comment: This sql server is not shared.  The sql logs show:
Starting up database
Parallel redo is starting
Parallel redo is shutdown for database
and a bunch of index restored for database
ex. database.syspriorities, database.sysprufiles, database.sysowners, etc.
The sharepoint config db appears under databases but admin db does not.  The admin db will appear under databases if I run the ps script again but the deadlock error still appears.